# Determining lat/long of location when in UTM projected map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am working in an ArcMap MXD, where all my layers and the dataframe are in UTM 19N.  What's the easiest method to determine the lat/long of any point (a random point of interest) within my map?

Do I have to re-project a layer to do so?  Or is there a method where I can just click and get a value in lat/long?

Comment: Have you tried Identify?  How do you define easiest?  Least number of clicks or least prep or something else ...? Have you tried changing your display units on the data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your correctly, you need to display the units in degree minute second instead of meter. If so, you can just right-click in the view map and go to General tab, and change the display unit from meter to degree minute second, as you can see below:

[image]

[image]